# web services calling error in flex

Tags: flex4

When i call web services, i got below mentioned error

```
[FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="Error #1098: Illegal prefix ns0 for no namespace." faultCode="EncodingError" faultDetail="null"] messageId=null type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]
<mx:WebService id="myWebService1" wsdl="URL">
  <mx:operation name="loginservice" result="getMonths_result(event);" fault="getMonths_fault(event);">              
  </mx:operation>
</mx:WebService>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about flex4 but it seems that there is a XML document somewere wich has prefixed elements (`<ns0:Element>`) but it has not a defined namespace (`xmlns:ns0 = "URI"`).

OR

There is not an URI in the namespace definition (`xmlns:ns0 = ""`)